# Converting row values into a column array in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on spark dataframes and I need to do a group by of a column and convert the column values of grouped rows into an array of elements as new column.
Example :

```
Input:

employee | Address
------------------
Micheal  |  NY
Micheal  |  NJ

Output:

employee | Address
------------------
Micheal  | (NY,NJ)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.!

Comment: Seems like you can use groupByKey to get what you want, which will give you an Iterable of [Address].

Comment: @Manas this is the error i get groupByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Comment: show us your code.....

Comment: Hi @vds say your dataframe is Input => you write `Input.groupBy(Input.col("employee"))` . You can take a look at spark API reference.

Comment: look at `collect_list()`

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternate solution 
Where I have converted the dataframe to an rdd for the transformations and converted it back a dataFrame using `sqlContext.createDataFrame()`

Sample.json

```
{"employee":"Michale","Address":"NY"}
{"employee":"Michale","Address":"NJ"}
{"employee":"Sam","Address":"NY"}
{"employee":"Max","Address":"NJ"}
```

Spark Application

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("sample.json")

// Printing the original Df
df.show()

//Defining the Schema for the aggregated DataFrame
val dataSchema = new StructType(
  Array(
    StructField("employee", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("Address", ArrayType(StringType, containsNull = true), nullable = true)
  )
)
// Converting the df to rdd and performing the groupBy operation
val aggregatedRdd: RDD[Row] = df.rdd.groupBy(r =>
          r.getAs[String]("employee")
        ).map(row =>
          // Mapping the Grouped Values to a new Row Object
          Row(row._1, row._2.map(_.getAs[String]("Address")).toArray)
        )

// Creating a DataFrame from the aggregatedRdd with the defined Schema (dataSchema)
val aggregatedDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(aggregatedRdd, dataSchema)

// Printing the aggregated Df
aggregatedDf.show()
```

Output :

```
+-------+--------+---+
|Address|employee|num|
+-------+--------+---+
|     NY| Michale|  1|
|     NJ| Michale|  2|
|     NY|     Sam|  3|
|     NJ|     Max|  4|
+-------+--------+---+

+--------+--------+
|employee| Address|
+--------+--------+
|     Sam|    [NY]|
| Michale|[NY, NJ]|
|     Max|    [NJ]|
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: This answer is OK but using RDD API is slower than using DataFrame API by a large margin (due to lack of query optimizer & tungsten)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using **Spark 2.0+**, you can use `collect_list` or `collect_set`.
Your query will be something like (assuming your dataframe is called **input**):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

input.groupBy('employee).agg(collect_list('Address))
```

If you are ok with duplicates, use `collect_list`. If you're not ok with duplicates and only need unique items in the list, use `collect_set`.

Hope this helps!