# Scala spark data frames group by with field merging

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have data frame with 5 rows:

```
[user,sun,MainTest2,end,false]
[user,sun,MainTest2,start,false]
[user,sun,MainTest,end,true]
[user,sun,MainTest,start,true]
[user,sun,MainTest,start,true]
```

What i wan't to achieve is 2 aggregated rows with text merged on 4 field:

```
[user,sun,MainTest2,end#some_union_symbol#start,false]
[user,sun,MainTest,end#some_union_symbol#start#some_union_symbol#start,true]
```

I think I need do something about reduce, but not quite sure.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332232/converting-row-values-into-a-column-array-in-spark-dataframe/38324499#38324499) from all stack that i can find and work with my 1.4.1 spark.

*sorry, for double post*